# Force Bootgrid pagination element to stay in one position relative to it's parent container regardless of the number of table rows?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-bootgrid

I am having trouble getting the pagination element of a JQuery Bootgrid table I am working on to stay in the correct position.  It seems to be positioned relative to the last table row no matter what I try. I have tried setting the container div to relative and using top, left, etc. but I couldn't get it to work. Here are some pics to show the current positioning of the pagination:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to get the pagination positioned similarly to the button labeled "Click Me!". This is where I want the element to be permanently, no matter how many items are in the table:
[image]

The pagination element can be targeted using this:

" #form .bootgrid-footer .pagination, .bootgrid-header .pagination "

I have set up a demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1k5btepn/). The last entry in the CSS section is labeled as indicated above and will effect the styling of the Bootgrid pagination.

```
See JSFiddle
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/1k5btepn/3/

```
#grid-command-buttons-footer .col-sm-6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
}
```

The issue is that if you set the .pagination elements CSS, even if it is `absolute`, it is still relative to the `.col-sm-6` element (because `.col-` classes are `position: relative`).  But, if you target the correct `.col-sm-6` element, you can position *it* the way you want.