# How to set bootgrid pagination control above table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, jquery-bootgrid

How can I change he pagination control to show at the top of the table and over its heading row, rather than at the bottom?

This is probably a CSS answer...

I tried playing around according to the suggestion in the following unanswered question but to no avail: [Force Bootgrid pagination element to stay in one position relative to it's parent container regardless of the number of table rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981771/force-bootgrid-pagination-element-to-stay-in-one-position-relative-to-its-paren)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/documentation#templates - it sounds like a custom header and footer template are what you want - start with the defaults in the library, of course.

Absolute positioning would be a CSS thing, if you also want that.